# How do I make the name of a new Facebook page accept capitalization for a surname?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

The automated system is preventing me from naming my page with my surname. I am creating a page to promote my photography and would like to use my brand, Jared McGuire Photography.

However Facebook gives this error: Our automated system will not allow the name "Jared McGuire Photography". We have suggested "Jared Mcguire Photography".

A quick search shows many pages that have words with pascal casing, like McDonald's. I understand the reason for this restriction and there is obviously a way around if for valid uses.

**How do I get around this restriction in order to use my surname?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can simply edit the name after creation.